# Java SSL/TLS with Anonymous Diffie Hellman

Tags: java, ssl

I have a basic client/server application written in Java which uses plain Sockets for communication.

I'd like to prevent passive eavesdropping attacks against it and do the communication over TLS/SSL. I don't want the application user to get in the hassle of setting up certificates etc., I'd like to setup Sockets over SSL with Anonymous Diffie Hellman using AES encryption (TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA mode).

However I can't find any suitable examples on net or any documentation as to how I'd setup the SSLContext or SSLSocketFactory to enable the mode I want. I'd appreciate a minimal example for this.

Comment: You are aware that the anonymous cipher suites are insecure?

Comment: EJP, As I've stated in my question that my goal is to protect against "passive eavesdropping", I think it fulfills my requirement of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the cipher suite on the `SSLSocket` (or `SSLEngine`) using [`setEnabledCipherSuites`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledCipherSuites%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).

Comment: On the `SSLSocket` you get from your factory, call `setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" }`. As EJP said, anonymous cipher suites are insecure against MITM attacks. Often, attackers in a position to perform passive eavesdropping are also in a position to perform MITM attacks.

Comment: I wish I could use TLS-PSK but Java doesn't have it :(

Comment: If getting certificates is a problem, you can always use self-signed certificates that you import explicitly in your trust store. I doubt PSK would require less configuration than that.