# How to force the use of Diffie Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: java, ssl, diffie-hellman

I want to create a TLS Socket connection. I know TLS has a few ways to exchange the key eg. RSA, Diffie-Hellman, etc. How can I force the use of Diffie-Hellman key exchange instead of other forms of key exchange?

I know that if using Diffie-Hellman key exchange, it is vulnerable to man-in-middle attack. When using RSA, we have server authentication which prevents MITM. But one concern I have is that using RSA prohibits the forward secrecy.

What should I do?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846017/java-ssl-tls-with-anonymous-diffie-hellman

Comment: What you "know" is false. Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman cipher suites *can* authenticate the server, preventing MITM attacks, while offering forward secrecy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the key exchange method is done by choosing a cipher suite that supports that key exchange method.

You can the cipher suite on an `SSLSocket` (or `SSLEngine`) using [`setEnabledCipherSuites`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledCipherSuites%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).

The tables of supported cipher suites and those enabled by default with the Oracle JRE are available in the [SunJSSE provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider).

The anonymous cipher suites (`_DH_anon_`) are the ones that are vulnerable to MITM attacks.

The `_DH_RSA_` or `_DH_DSA_` cipher suites also use RSA or DSA for the authentication of the DH key exchange (not for the key exchange itself), to prevent MITM attacks. In addition, the *Ephemeral* DH cipher suites (those that contain `_DHE_`, or `_ECDHE_` for the elliptic curve variant) provide Perfect Forward Secrecy. (The non-ephemeral `_DH_RSA_` or `_DH_DSA_` cipher suites are not supported by the Sun JSSE provider anyway.)