# How to connect to an SSL Server in Java that doesn't send a certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a situation where an Open SSL server is running without a certificate as follows :
openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert

How do I connect to this server using Java? Also, how do I start my server in Java to accept no certificate?

I have attached the code for Client.java and Server.java that I have been using.

Error while running the attached code on the client side:

```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at Client.main(Client.java:27)
```

Error on the Server Side :

```
ERROR
140387701290656:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1358:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] arstring) {
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 4443);            
        //sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslsocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" }); //Added upon suggestion from Steffan

        boolean test = sslsocket.isConnected();
        System.out.println(test);
        InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
        System.out.println("1");
        OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("2");
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream,"UTF-8");
        String str = "hello\n";
        outputstreamwriter.write(str,0,str.length());
        //outputstreamwriter.flush();
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

        String string = null;
        int count = 0;
        string = bufferedreader.readLine();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(string);                
            System.out.flush();
            System.out.println(++count);
            string = bufferedreader.readLine();
            if (inputstream.available()==0)
                break;
            else{
                System.out.print("StreamData:");
                System.out.println(inputstream.available());
            }


        }
        System.out.println("Out");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server {
public static  void main(String[] arstring) {
    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServersocketFactory =
                (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket =
                (SSLServerSocket) sslServersocketFactory.createServerSocket(4443);
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());

        if (sslSocket.isConnected())
            System.out.println("Connected to a client");

        InputStream inputStream = sslSocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String command = "";
        String response = "";

        while ((command = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("Command Recieved: "+command);

                if (command.toLowerCase().compareTo("hello")==0)
                    response = "Bingo !! You got it write!\n";
                else
                    response = "Type Hello to see a response\n";


                OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                outputStreamWriter.write(response, 0, response.length());
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Edit:

I think I need to use the anonymous DH Cipher but it's still not working. May be I am doing it wrong. The code has been edited too.

Comment: You have to use ADH ciphers, see  [Java SSL/TLS with Anonymous Diffie Hellman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846017/java-ssl-tls-with-anonymous-diffie-hellman)

Comment: But if you don't want it secure why use SSL at all?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Can you give any links to the code example on how to set that cipher? Or probably edit my code and show it there?
I tried but it is giving handshake_failure
I have made modifications to the above code too.

Comment: @user3667569: the linked question contains such code already in the comments.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : It is still giving handshake_failure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless a cipher is explicitly given `s_server` uses the set `DEFAULT` which does not include ADH ciphers. Try with `openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert -cipher ADH-AES128-SHA`.

Comment: The problem is I can't do that. I have to start the server as 
`openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert`

Is there any other way to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to connect to an SSL Server in Java that doesn't send a certificate?

If its not sending a certificate, then its probably using (1) one of the preshared keys cipher suites, like TLS-SRP or TLS-PSK, or (2) its using Anonymous Diffie-Hellman.

The preshared key cipher suites are usually choices because they provide mutual authentication and channel binding.

Anonymous Diffie-Hellman is usually a bad choice because it lacks server authentication.

---

> I have a situation where an Open SSL server is running without a certificate as follows : openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert

Well, there you have it.

---

> How do I connect to this server using Java? Also, how do I start my server in Java to accept no certificate?

Use a cipher suite that includes an anonymous exchange, like:

- ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
- ADH-AES128-SHA
- ADH-AES256-SHA
- ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA
- ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA
- ADH-SEED-SHA
- ADH-AES128-SHA256
- ADH-AES256-SHA256
- ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384

You can get the mapping of `ADH-AES128-SHA` to `TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` at the [openssl ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) man page.

You might try the command:

```
openssl s_server -accept 4443 -tls1 -nocert -cipher "HIGH"
```

By enabling TLS1, you side step any potential issues where one side or the other disables SSLv2 and SSLv3 (which is a good thing), but you only provide SSLv3 (which is a bad thing).

The cipher suite list string `"HIGH"` includes ADH by default (in production, usually you do `"HIGH:!ADH:!RC4:!MD5..."`).

Comment: thanks, it cleared out a lot... but I have been giving a scenario specifically to connect to a server running this `openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert`
The client has no other info and I certainly can't specify any ciphers while starting the server

Comment: @user3667569 I don't think you'll ever be able to connect to such a server if you don't specify any cipher on the server side. You can't even connect to it using `openssl s_client -connect localhost:4443 -cipher ALL`.

Comment: @Bruno yeah I tried that too but is there absolutely no loop hole? I am hoping there is because a lot depends upon this

Comment: @user3667569 Not enabling anonymous cipher suites by default is generally done by design (more or less [as recommended by the specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-D.3)). Loopholes are generally not welcome in SSL/TLS implementations: they're actually called **vulnerabilities**. It sounds like whoever set up that `s_server` for you weren't quite sure what they were doing and they'll have to reconsider (mistakes happen). Of course, setting up a certificate would be much better than using anonymous cipher suites (even if it's self-signed, you could at least pin it somehow).

Comment: @Bruno I have to say, I agree with you but if there is no way to connect a server when started as `openssl s_server -accept 4443 -nocert` then why is this still a valid command? I mean shouldn't it be disallowed or something?

Comment: @user3667569 I'm not sure `s_client` and `s_server` where ever intended to be used as full applications. I'd think of them as part of a testing toolbox. The `s_server` man-page clearly says "*s_server can be used to debug SSL clients.*" (which doesn't preclude other uses indeed) and "*Because this program has a lot of options and also because some of the techniques used are rather old, the C source of s_server is rather hard to read and not a model of how things should be done.*" (the rest of the bugs section may also be relevant regarding cipher suites).

Comment: Quibbles: TLS also defines, and OpenSSL 1.0.0+ and Java 7+ implement, ECDH_anon suites which OpenSSL calls AECDH. Thus with OpenSSL HIGH (or MEDIUM or ALL) you usually want to exclude `!ADH:!AECDH` or easier `!aNULL` which covers both; the default (which OP is apparently stuck with) does exactly `!aNULL`, so it is still unusable. OTOH `-tls1` isn't a good idea; it would prevent SSLv3 (good) but also prevent TLSv1.1 and 1.2 (very bad). OpenSSL 1.0.0+ with default or sane ciphers already won't accept SSLv2; to reject SSLv3 use `-no_ssl3`.